# TinyMCE error: Cannot read property 'body' of null

Tags: tinymce

This how I am initializing it. The problem comes in when opening on the second time. And this only happens in Chrome. Mozilla Firefox works well.

```
tinyMCE.init({
          mode : "exact",
          elements : "email_content",
          theme : "advanced",
          theme_advanced_resizing : true,
          plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
          theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
          theme_advanced_buttons2 : "bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,code,|,forecolor,backcolor"
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after chrome update(version 85) , but this line before tinyMCE.init works to me:

```
tinyMCE.EditorManager.editors = [];
```

or

```
tinyMCE.editors = [];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to resolve the issue this way with TinyMCE version 4.3.13. I'd tried tinyMCE.remove() before should have had the same effect, but to no avail. Any ideas - apart from upgrading?

Comment: We were able to resolve our issue with this fix. However TinyMCE version 3.8 is the one we are using in our product.

Comment: It's work to me  >>>  tinyMCE.editors = []; <<<<
But you must need insert it before tinymse.init or any else methods.